# Extender controls may not be registered after PreRender

Tags: asp.net, ajax, prerender

I am creating Dynamic UserControls with Dynamic AjaxControls. Then I store each of the UserControls in a Collection. On Postback I recall the UserControls in the collection to Re-Create the interface. It works if i only use Standard HTML controls but does NOT work with AJAX controls. I get this error on PostBack **Extender controls may not be registered after PreRender**. So far I have tried the following:

1. MyBase.OnPreRender(e) in Page and Usercontrol
2. EnsureChildControls() in the OnInit
3. Added ScriptManager to the MasterPage
   None of this stuff is working...

If I re-create all the controls including the ones inside the usercontrol then i get no error however it takes forever to do a postback as opposed to just recalling the collection of UserControls.

Stack Trace:

at System.Web.UI.ScriptControlManager.RegisterExtenderControl[TExtenderControl](TExtenderControl extenderControl, Control targetControl)

at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterExtenderControl[TExtenderControl](TExtenderControl extenderControl, Control targetControl)

at System.Web.UI.ExtenderControl.RegisterWithScriptManager()

at System.Web.UI.ExtenderControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)

at AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderControlBase.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) in 
d:\hg\act\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs:line 365

at AjaxControlToolkit.DropDownExtender.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) in d:\hg\act\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\DropDown\DropDownExtender.cs:line 157

at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()

at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()

at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()

at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()

at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()

at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()

at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()

at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()

at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()

at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()

at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()

at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()

at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()

at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()

at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: If you're attempting to recreate a dynamic control set on postback you should do so in the OnInit method. You may also want to post the stack trace of your error and the relevant method, as that could help us diagnose the issue.

Comment: I tried that but does not work. And I've tried it on Page_Load too.

Comment: The thing that you posted doesn't look like an exception call stack. Maybe you posted the debugger output instead of the call stack from the exception. The call stack from the exception would be more helpful.

Comment: Ok. After debugging when I got the Exception I expanded the Detials and copied the Stack Trace above. will that work.

Comment: Are you dynamically recreating the extenders as well as the user controls? Would you not be better to declaratively define the extenders in the user controls?